# Autoboxing Unboxing Operator (!=) and (==) difference

Tags: java, autoboxing, unboxing

```
public class T1 {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Integer i1 = 1000;
        Integer i2 = 1000;
        if(i1 != i2) System.out.println("different objects");
        if(i1.equals(i2)) System.out.println("meaningfully equal");    

    }

}
```

O/P for this is:

> different objects
>   meaningfully equal

Where as

```
public class T2 {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {            

        Integer i3 = 10;
        Integer i4 = 10;
        if(i3!=i4)System.out.println("Crap dude!!");
        if(i3 == i4) System.out.println("same object");

        if(i3.equals(i4)) System.out.println("meaningfully equal");    
    }

}
```

Produces Following O/P:

> same object
>   meaningfully equal

I didn't understand why in class `T2` `if(i3!=i4)` didn't get triggered I'm refering SCJP 1.6 but not able to understand.
Please help me.

Comment: Note that you used "1000" in the first example and "10" in the second example.

Comment: Learn about cache range for integers in Java. Read Javadoc, source code, ... of `Integer` wrapper class.

Comment: Ok.. thanks kenny and Rohit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because 10 is in between the range [-128, 127]. For this range `==` works fine since the JVM caches the values and the comparison will be made on the *same* object.

Every time an `Integer` (object) is created with value in that range, the same object will be returned instead of creating the *new* object.

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) for further information.

Comment: **This can be wrong**, since `Integer.valueOf` does caching, the constructor can't. The compiler internally compiles `Integer i = 0;` to `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(0);`, which is why this works in this case.

Answer (score 4):

There is Integer pool for the numbers from `-128 to 127` in java. [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) says

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127
>   (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.
>
> Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an
>   identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using
>   existing implementation techniques. The rules above are a pragmatic
>   compromise. The final clause above requires that certain common values
>   always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. The implementation may
>   cache these, lazily or eagerly. For other values, this formulation
>   disallows any assumptions about the identity of the boxed values on
>   the programmer's part. This would allow (but not require) sharing of
>   some or all of these references.
>
> This ensures that in most common cases, the behavior will be the
>   desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially
>   on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might, for
>   example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long
>   values in the range of -32K to +32K.

Answer (score 4):

Small integers get interned, meaning that there's only one instance of `Integer` for the given value.

This doesn't happen for large integers, hence the difference in behaviour between your two tests.

Comment: so if we are creating two objects of Integer within [-128 to 127]
with same value then only one object with that value would be created and they both reference variables would be pointing to that object. Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

Integer are cached between range -128 to 127. so Integer in between the range(containing boundary values) will return the same reference..

like

```
Integer i3 = 127;
Integer i4 = 127;
Integer i5 = 128;

 if(i3!=i4)System.out.println("Crap dude!!");   // same reference
 if(i3 == i4) System.out.println("same object"); 
 if(i3 != i5) System.out.println("different object");
```

output..

```
same object
different object
```

As '==' compares reference and 'equals' compares content.  for more detail You may go to
[Immutable Objects / Wrapper Class Caching](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas)

Comment: I think output should be 
Crap dude!!
different object.

Comment: You might have misspelled 1 (i4). Did you mean 127?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma, dude output is same as written above..

Comment: @TarunChaudhary I tried it it gives Crap dude!! different object.
And i agree this output because 127 and 1 both are different values so they can't be meaningfully equal.

Comment: oh now you edited that right :D previously it was 1.

Answer (score 2):

anyway you can get double false with:

```
Integer n1 = -1000;
Integer n2 = -1000;

Integer p1 = 1000;
Integer p2 = 1000;

System.out.println(n1 == n2);
System.out.println(p1 != p2);
```

there is an option to set max size of this Integer pool

```
  /**
   * Cache to support the object identity semantics of autoboxing for values between
   * -128 and 127 (inclusive) as required by JLS.
   *
   * The cache is initialized on first usage.  The size of the cache
   * may be controlled by the -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size> option.
   * During VM initialization, java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high property
   * may be set and saved in the private system properties in the
   * sun.misc.VM class.
   */
```